# Нажимаю на кнопку, всплывает окно, как перейти в него?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь автоматизировать один процесс на сайте https://ati.su/.
Суть заключается в том, чтобы нажать на выделенную кнопку, а затем нажать сохранить, это всё. При нажатии открывается новое окно, каким образом можно нажать на кнопку (в всплывающем окне).
[image: После нажатия этой кнопки, открывается новое окно]

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYuEu.png]

Можно ли как-то переключится на новое окно? (использую selenium + python)
Код:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep


def get_url(driver):  # perehodim po ssilkam
    driver.get("https://id.ati.su/login/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fati.su%2F&iframe=1&fastreg=1")
    print("GOT URL")
    sleep(6)


def authorization(driver):
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(600, 390).click().send_keys(login).perform()
    sleep(2)
    print("LOGIN +")

    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(0, 50).click().send_keys(password).perform()
    sleep(2)
    print("PASSWORD +")

    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(-170, 120).click().perform()
    sleep(5)
    print("AUTHORIZATION ")


def clicker(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='header']/div[contains(@class, '_34FgW-0-0-271')]/div[contains(@class, 'sticky-submenu')]/div[contains(@class, 'sticky-outer-wrapper')]/div[contains(@class, 'sticky-inner-wrapper')]/div[contains(@class, 'nzRdz-0-0-271')]/nav[contains(@class, '_2h2n--0-0-271')]/ul[contains(@class, '_3Wszn-0-0-271')]/li[contains(@class, 'list-item')]/a[contains(@class, '_1Wk8T-0-0-271')]/span[contains(@class, '_3hASI-0-0-271')]").click()
    sleep(2)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='react-select-2--value-item' and contains(@class, 'Select-value-label')]/div[contains(@class, 'selected-value')]/span[contains(@class, 'selected-option-label')]")
    element.click()
    sleep(3)
    # MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
    # webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(200, 300).click().perform()
    # sleep(3)
    divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ati-glyph-button glyph-load-edit']")
    for div in divs:
        div.click()
        sleep(3)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("button[@class='ati-button blue-button ati-button-primary']")
            sleep(2)
        except:
            pass
    print("CLICK VSE GRUZI +")



def main():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7')
    # options.add_extension("D:\\UB\\cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm.crx")
    # options.add_extension("D:\\UB\\page-ruller.crx")
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="D:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    get_url(driver)
    authorization(driver)
    clicker(driver)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/how-to-switch-to-the-new-browser-window-which-opens-after-click-on-the-button